# How can I change the way my computer shuts down

Tags: windows, shutdown

Its late at night, I shut down my computer and go to bed. The next morning, I wake up and to my horror, my computer is still on.

It seems that Windows did not shutdown because of another program prompting me to save my work.

How can I make sure Windows forces shutdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Launch *regedit* to access the registry editor.
2. Search for the following Registry Key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop`
3. Create a new **string value** named **AutoEndTasks** and set its value to 1.

This should prevent Windows from gracefully shutting down and will automatically terminate running process.

For something more granular:

- Search for the following Registry Key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control`
- Edit the **WaitToKillServiceTimeout** value.

For active user programs such as Word, which asks if you like to quit without saving etc.

- Search for the following Registry Key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control
  Panel\Desktop`
- Create two Reg_SZ values Key - **HungAppTimeout** and **WaitToKillAppTimeout**
- Modify their value as required, *WaitToKillAppTimeout* represents the window of time in which a application need to respond before fordibly being killed. *HungAppTimeout* specifies the window of time to allow for an app to exit before being deemed unresponsive.

Full article detailing the process [here](http://winaero.com/blog/speed-up-slow-shutdown-in-windows-10/).

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, but I will wait before accepting for another, safer way of doing it.

Comment: I edited my answer to include more use cases, feel free to check them out.